# Google Calendar API querying all events for the last 1 months in Python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am looking into this [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) from Google Calendar API. It shows 10 events starting from now to the future.

```
eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

I need to find out all the events for the last 1 month. I understand I need to use `timeMax` variable but not sure how to specify it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the calendar of `primary`, you want to retrieve events for the last 1 month from now. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? `timeMin` and `timeMax` are required to be RFC3339 timestamp.

#### Modified script :

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = datetime.today()
monthAgo = today - relativedelta(months=1)
tmax = today.isoformat('T') + "Z"
tmin = monthAgo.isoformat('T') + "Z"
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId='primary',
    timeMin=tmin,
    timeMax=tmax,
    maxResults=10,
    singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime',
).execute()
```

#### Reference :

- [list for calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.